# hyperkube doesn't start any manifest from /etc/kubernetes/manifests

Tags: kubernetes, coreos, rkt, kubelet, containeros

I have Container Linux by CoreOS alpha (1325.1.0) Installed on a pc at home.

I played with kubernetes for a couple of month, but now after reinstalling ContainerOS and trying to install kubernetes using my fork at https://github.com/kfirufk/coreos-kubernetes I fail to properly install kubernetes.

I use hyperkube image `v1.6.0-beta.0_coreos.0`.

the problem is that it seems that hyperkube doesn't try to initiate any manifests from `/etc/kubernetes/manifests`. I configured kubelet to run with rkt.

when I run `journalctl -xef -u kubelet` after restarting kubelet, I get the following output:

```
Feb 26 20:17:33 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: + exec /usr/bin/rkt run --uuid-file-save=/var/run/kubelet-pod.uuid --volume dns,kind=host,source=/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf --mount volume=dns,target=/etc/resolv.conf --volume rkt,kind=host,source=/opt/bin/host-rkt --mount volume=rkt,target=/usr/bin/rkt --volume var-lib-rkt,kind=host,source=/var/lib/rkt --mount volume=var-lib-rkt,target=/var/lib/rkt --volume stage,kind=host,source=/tmp --mount volume=stage,target=/tmp --volume var-log,kind=host,source=/var/log --mount volume=var-log,target=/var/log --volume cni-bin,kind=host,source=/opt/cni/bin --mount volume=cni-bin,target=/opt/cni/bin --trust-keys-from-https --volume etc-kubernetes,kind=host,source=/etc/kubernetes,readOnly=false --volume etc-ssl-certs,kind=host,source=/etc/ssl/certs,readOnly=true --volume usr-share-certs,kind=host,source=/usr/share/ca-certificates,readOnly=true --volume var-lib-docker,kind=host,source=/var/lib/docker,readOnly=false --volume var-lib-kubelet,kind=host,source=/var/lib/kubelet,readOnly=false --volume os-release,kind=host,source=/usr/lib/os-release,readOnly=true --volume run,kind=host,source=/run,readOnly=false --mount volume=etc-kubernetes,target=/etc/kubernetes --mount volume=etc-ssl-certs,target=/etc/ssl/certs --mount volume=usr-share-certs,target=/usr/share/ca-certificates --mount volume=var-lib-docker,target=/var/lib/docker --mount volume=var-lib-kubelet,target=/var/lib/kubelet --mount volume=os-release,target=/etc/os-release --mount volume=run,target=/run --stage1-from-dir=stage1-fly.aci quay.io/coreos/hyperkube:v1.6.0-beta.0_coreos.0 --exec=/kubelet -- --require-kubeconfig --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/controller-kubeconfig.yaml --register-schedulable=true --cni-conf-dir=/etc/kubernetes/cni/net.d --network-plugin=kubenet --container-runtime=rkt --rkt-path=/usr/bin/rkt --allow-privileged=true --pod-manifest-path=/etc/kubernetes/manifests --hostname-override=192.168.1.2 --cluster_dns=10.3.0.10 --cluster_domain=cluster.local
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: Flag --register-schedulable has been deprecated, will be removed in a future version
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: I0226 20:17:41.260305    3673 feature_gate.go:170] feature gates: map[]
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: I0226 20:17:41.332539    3673 manager.go:143] cAdvisor running in container: "/system.slice/kubelet.service"
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: I0226 20:17:41.355270    3673 fs.go:117] Filesystem partitions: map[/dev/mapper/usr:{mountpoint:/usr/lib/os-release major:254 minor:0 fsType:ext4 blockSize:0} /dev/sda9:{mountpoint:/var/lib/docker major:8 minor:9 fsType:ext4 blockSize:0} /dev/sdb1:{mountpoint:/var/lib/rkt major:8 minor:17 fsType:ext4 blockSize:0}]
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: I0226 20:17:41.359173    3673 manager.go:198] Machine: {NumCores:8 CpuFrequency:3060000 MemoryCapacity:4145344512 MachineID:b07a180a2c8547f7956e9a6f93a452a4 SystemUUID:00000000-0000-0000-0000-1C6F653E6F72 BootID:c03de69b-c9c8-4fb7-a3df-de4f70a74218 Filesystems:[{Device:/dev/mapper/usr Capacity:1031946240 Type:vfs Inodes:260096 HasInodes:true} {Device:/dev/sda9 Capacity:113819422720 Type:vfs Inodes:28536576 HasInodes:true} {Device:/dev/sdb1 Capacity:984373800960 Type:vfs Inodes:61054976 HasInodes:true} {Device:overlay Capacity:984373800960 Type:vfs Inodes:61054976 HasInodes:true}] DiskMap:map[254:0:{Name:dm-0 Major:254 Minor:0 Size:1065345024 Scheduler:none} 8:0:{Name:sda Major:8 Minor:0 Size:120034123776 Scheduler:cfq} 8:16:{Name:sdb Major:8 Minor:16 Size:1000204886016 Scheduler:cfq} 8:32:{Name:sdc Major:8 Minor:32 Size:3000592982016 Scheduler:cfq} 8:48:{Name:sdd Major:8 Minor:48 Size:2000398934016 Scheduler:cfq} 8:64:{Name:sde Major:8 Minor:64 Size:1000204886016 Scheduler:cfq}] NetworkDevices:[{Name:enp3s0 MacAddress:1c:6f:65:3e:6f:72 Speed:1000 Mtu:1500} {Name:flannel.1 MacAddress:be:f8:31:12:15:f5 Speed:0 Mtu:1450}] Topology:[{Id:0 Memory:4145344512 Cores:[{Id:0 Threads:[0 4] Caches:[{Size:32768 Type:Data Level:1} {Size:32768 Type:Instruction Level:1} {Size:262144 Type:Unified Level:2}]} {Id:1 Threads:[1 5] Caches:[{Size:32768 Type:Data Level:1} {Size:32768 Type:Instruction Level:1} {Size:262144 Type:Unified Level:2}]} {Id:2 Threads:[2 6] Caches:[{Size:32768 Type:Data Level:1} {Size:32768 Type:Instruction Level:1} {Size:262144 Type:Unified Level:2}]} {Id:3 Threads:[3 7] Caches:[{Size:32768 Type:Data Level:1} {Size:32768 Type:Instruction Level:1} {Size:262144 Type:Unified Level:2}]}] Caches:[{Size:8388608 Type:Unified Level:3}]}] CloudProvider:Unknown InstanceType:Unknown InstanceID:None}
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: I0226 20:17:41.359768    3673 manager.go:204] Version: {KernelVersion:4.9.9-coreos-r1 ContainerOsVersion:Container Linux by CoreOS 1325.1.0 (Ladybug) DockerVersion:1.13.1 CadvisorVersion: CadvisorRevision:}
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: I0226 20:17:41.362754    3673 kubelet.go:253] Adding manifest file: /etc/kubernetes/manifests
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: I0226 20:17:41.362800    3673 kubelet.go:263] Watching apiserver
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: W0226 20:17:41.366369    3673 kubelet_network.go:63] Hairpin mode set to "promiscuous-bridge" but container runtime is "rkt", ignoring
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: I0226 20:17:41.366427    3673 kubelet.go:494] Hairpin mode set to "none"
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: I0226 20:17:41.379778    3673 server.go:790] Started kubelet v1.6.0-beta.0+coreos.0
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: E0226 20:17:41.379803    3673 kubelet.go:1143] Image garbage collection failed: unable to find data for container /
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: I0226 20:17:41.379876    3673 server.go:125] Starting to listen on 0.0.0.0:10250
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: I0226 20:17:41.380252    3673 kubelet_node_status.go:238] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: E0226 20:17:41.381083    3673 kubelet.go:1631] Failed to check if disk space is available for the runtime: failed to get fs info for "runtime": unable to find data for container /
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: E0226 20:17:41.381120    3673 kubelet.go:1639] Failed to check if disk space is available on the root partition: failed to get fs info for "root": unable to find data for container /
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: I0226 20:17:41.381658    3673 server.go:288] Adding debug handlers to kubelet server.
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: I0226 20:17:41.382281    3673 fs_resource_analyzer.go:66] Starting FS ResourceAnalyzer
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: I0226 20:17:41.382310    3673 status_manager.go:140] Starting to sync pod status with apiserver
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: I0226 20:17:41.382326    3673 kubelet.go:1711] Starting kubelet main sync loop.
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: I0226 20:17:41.382354    3673 kubelet.go:1722] skipping pod synchronization - [container runtime is down PLEG is not healthy: pleg was last seen active 2562047h47m16.854775807s ago; threshold is 3m0s]
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: I0226 20:17:41.382616    3673 volume_manager.go:248] Starting Kubelet Volume Manager
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: E0226 20:17:41.386643    3673 kubelet.go:2028] Container runtime status is nil
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: E0226 20:17:41.436430    3673 event.go:208] Unable to write event: 'Post https://coreos-2.tux-in.com:443/api/v1/namespaces/default/events: dial tcp 192.168.1.2:443: getsockopt: connection refused' (may retry after sleeping)
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: E0226 20:17:41.436547    3673 reflector.go:190] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:46: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://coreos-2.tux-in.com:443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3D192.168.1.2&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.1.2:443: getsockopt: connection refused
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: E0226 20:17:41.436547    3673 reflector.go:190] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:380: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://coreos-2.tux-in.com:443/api/v1/services?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.1.2:443: getsockopt: connection refused
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: E0226 20:17:41.436557    3673 reflector.go:190] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:388: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://coreos-2.tux-in.com:443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3D192.168.1.2&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.1.2:443: getsockopt: connection refused
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: I0226 20:17:41.482996    3673 kubelet_node_status.go:238] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: E0226 20:17:41.483717    3673 kubelet.go:1631] Failed to check if disk space is available for the runtime: failed to get fs info for "runtime": unable to find data for container /
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: E0226 20:17:41.483774    3673 kubelet.go:1639] Failed to check if disk space is available on the root partition: failed to get fs info for "root": unable to find data for container /
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: I0226 20:17:41.483907    3673 kubelet_node_status.go:78] Attempting to register node 192.168.1.2
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: E0226 20:17:41.556064    3673 kubelet_node_status.go:102] Unable to register node "192.168.1.2" with API server: Post https://coreos-2.tux-in.com:443/api/v1/nodes: dial tcp 192.168.1.2:443: getsockopt: connection refused
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: I0226 20:17:41.756398    3673 kubelet_node_status.go:238] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: E0226 20:17:41.757047    3673 kubelet.go:1631] Failed to check if disk space is available for the runtime: failed to get fs info for "runtime": unable to find data for container /
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: E0226 20:17:41.757087    3673 kubelet.go:1639] Failed to check if disk space is available on the root partition: failed to get fs info for "root": unable to find data for container /
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: I0226 20:17:41.757152    3673 kubelet_node_status.go:78] Attempting to register node 192.168.1.2
Feb 26 20:17:41 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: E0226 20:17:41.833244    3673 kubelet_node_status.go:102] Unable to register node "192.168.1.2" with API server: Post https://coreos-2.tux-in.com:443/api/v1/nodes: dial tcp 192.168.1.2:443: getsockopt: connection refused
Feb 26 20:17:42 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: I0226 20:17:42.233574    3673 kubelet_node_status.go:238] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
Feb 26 20:17:42 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: E0226 20:17:42.234232    3673 kubelet.go:1631] Failed to check if disk space is available for the runtime: failed to get fs info for "runtime": unable to find data for container /
Feb 26 20:17:42 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: E0226 20:17:42.234266    3673 kubelet.go:1639] Failed to check if disk space is available on the root partition: failed to get fs info for "root": unable to find data for container /
Feb 26 20:17:42 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: I0226 20:17:42.234324    3673 kubelet_node_status.go:78] Attempting to register node 192.168.1.2
Feb 26 20:17:42 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: E0226 20:17:42.306213    3673 kubelet_node_status.go:102] Unable to register node "192.168.1.2" with API server: Post https://coreos-2.tux-in.com:443/api/v1/nodes: dial tcp 192.168.1.2:443: getsockopt: connection refused
Feb 26 20:17:42 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: E0226 20:17:42.512768    3673 reflector.go:190] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:388: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://coreos-2.tux-in.com:443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3D192.168.1.2&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.1.2:443: getsockopt: connection refused
Feb 26 20:17:42 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: E0226 20:17:42.512810    3673 reflector.go:190] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:46: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://coreos-2.tux-in.com:443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3D192.168.1.2&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.1.2:443: getsockopt: connection refused
Feb 26 20:17:42 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: E0226 20:17:42.512905    3673 reflector.go:190] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:380: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://coreos-2.tux-in.com:443/api/v1/services?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.1.2:443: getsockopt: connection refused
Feb 26 20:17:43 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: I0226 20:17:43.106559    3673 kubelet_node_status.go:238] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
Feb 26 20:17:43 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: E0226 20:17:43.107210    3673 kubelet.go:1631] Failed to check if disk space is available for the runtime: failed to get fs info for "runtime": unable to find data for container /
Feb 26 20:17:43 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: E0226 20:17:43.107244    3673 kubelet.go:1639] Failed to check if disk space is available on the root partition: failed to get fs info for "root": unable to find data for container /
Feb 26 20:17:43 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: I0226 20:17:43.107304    3673 kubelet_node_status.go:78] Attempting to register node 192.168.1.2
Feb 26 20:17:43 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: E0226 20:17:43.186848    3673 kubelet_node_status.go:102] Unable to register node "192.168.1.2" with API server: Post https://coreos-2.tux-in.com:443/api/v1/nodes: dial tcp 192.168.1.2:443: getsockopt: connection refused
Feb 26 20:17:43 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: E0226 20:17:43.580259    3673 reflector.go:190] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:380: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://coreos-2.tux-in.com:443/api/v1/services?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.1.2:443: getsockopt: connection refused
Feb 26 20:17:43 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: E0226 20:17:43.580286    3673 reflector.go:190] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:388: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://coreos-2.tux-in.com:443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3D192.168.1.2&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.1.2:443: getsockopt: connection refused
Feb 26 20:17:43 coreos-2.tux-in.com kubelet-wrapper[3673]: E0226 20:17:43.580285    3673 reflector.go:190] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:46: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://coreos-2.tux-in.com:443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3D192.168.1.2&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.1.2:443: getsockopt: connection refused
```

my kubelet.service content (I tried with --network-plugin=kubenet and cni, makes no difference:

```
[Service]
Environment=KUBELET_IMAGE_TAG=v1.6.0-beta.0_coreos.0
Environment=KUBELET_IMAGE_URL=quay.io/coreos/hyperkube
Environment="RKT_RUN_ARGS=--uuid-file-save=/var/run/kubelet-pod.uuid \
  --volume dns,kind=host,source=/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf \
  --mount volume=dns,target=/etc/resolv.conf \
  --volume rkt,kind=host,source=/opt/bin/host-rkt \
  --mount volume=rkt,target=/usr/bin/rkt \
  --volume var-lib-rkt,kind=host,source=/var/lib/rkt \
  --mount volume=var-lib-rkt,target=/var/lib/rkt \
  --volume stage,kind=host,source=/tmp \
  --mount volume=stage,target=/tmp \
  --volume var-log,kind=host,source=/var/log \
  --mount volume=var-log,target=/var/log \
  --volume cni-bin,kind=host,source=/opt/cni/bin                    --mount volume=cni-bin,target=/opt/cni/bin"
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /etc/kubernetes/manifests
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /opt/cni/bin
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/log/containers
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/rkt rm --uuid-file=/var/run/kubelet-pod.uuid
ExecStart=/usr/lib/coreos/kubelet-wrapper \
  --require-kubeconfig \
  --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/controller-kubeconfig.yaml \
  --register-schedulable=true \
  --cni-conf-dir=/etc/kubernetes/cni/net.d \
  --network-plugin=kubenet \
  --container-runtime=rkt \
  --rkt-path=/usr/bin/rkt \
  --allow-privileged=true \
  --pod-manifest-path=/etc/kubernetes/manifests \
  --hostname-override=192.168.1.2 \
  --cluster_dns=10.3.0.10 \
  --cluster_domain=cluster.local
ExecStop=-/usr/bin/rkt stop --uuid-file=/var/run/kubelet-pod.uuid
Restart=always
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

my `/var/lib/coreos-install/user_data` file:

```
#cloud-config

hostname: "coreos-2.tux-in.com"
write_files:
 - path: "/etc/ssh/sshd_config"
   permissions: 0600
   owner: root:root
   content: |
     # Use most defaults for sshd configuration.
     UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox
     Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
     ClientAliveInterval 180
     UseDNS no
     UsePAM no
     PrintLastLog no # handled by PAM
     PrintMotd no # handled by PAMa
     PasswordAuthentication no
 - path: "/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.pem"
   permissions: "0666"
   content: |
     XXXX
 - path: "/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver.pem"
   permissions: "0666"
   content: |
     XXXX
 - path: "/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver-key.pem"
   permissions: "0666"
   content: |
     XXXX
 - path: "/etc/ssl/etcd/ca.pem"
   permissions: "0666"
   owner: "etcd:etcd"
   content: |
     XXXX
 - path: "/etc/ssl/etcd/etcd1.pem"
   permissions: "0666"
   owner: "etcd:etcd"
   content: |
     XXXX
 - path: "/etc/ssl/etcd/etcd1-key.pem"
   permissions: "0666"
   owner: "etcd:etcd"
   content: |
     XXXX
ssh_authorized_keys:
         - "XXXX ufk@ufk-osx-music"
users:
  - name: "ufk"
    passwd: "XXXX"
    groups:
      - "sudo"
    ssh-authorized-keys:
      - "ssh-rsa XXXX ufk@ufk-osx-music"
coreos:
  etcd2:
    # generate a new token for each unique cluster from https://discovery.etcd.io/new?size=3
    # specify the initial size of your cluster with ?size=X
    discovery: https://discovery.etcd.io/XXXX
    advertise-client-urls: https://coreos-2.tux-in.com:2379
    initial-advertise-peer-urls: https://coreos-2.tux-in.com:2380
    # listen on both the official ports and the legacy ports
    # legacy ports can be omitted if your application doesn't depend on them
    listen-client-urls: https://0.0.0.0:2379,http://127.0.0.1:4001
    listen-peer-urls: https://coreos-2.tux-in.com:2380
  locksmith:
    endpoint: "http://127.0.0.1:4001"
  update:
    reboot-strategy: etcd-lock
  units:
    - name: 00-enp3s0.network
      runtime: true
      content: |
       [Match]
       Name=enp3s0

       [Network]
       Address=192.168.1.2/16
       Gateway=192.168.1.1
       DNS=8.8.8.8
    - name: mnt-storage.mount
      enable: true
      command: start
      content: |
        [Mount]
        What=/dev/disk/by-uuid/e9df7e62-58da-4db2-8616-8947ac835e2c
        Where=/mnt/storage
        Type=btrfs
        Options=loop,discard
    - name: var-lib-rkt.mount
      enable: true
      command: start
      content: |
        [Mount]
        What=/dev/sdb1
        Where=/var/lib/rkt
        Type=ext4
    - name: etcd2.service
      command: start
      drop-ins:
       - name: 30-certs.conf
         content: |
          [Service]
          Restart=always
          Environment="ETCD_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/etcd1.pem"
          Environment="ETCD_KEY_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/etcd1-key.pem"
          Environment="ETCD_TRUSTED_CA_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/ca.pem"
          Environment="ETCD_CLIENT_CERT_AUTH=true"
          Environment="ETCD_PEER_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/etcd1.pem"
          Environment="ETCD_PEER_KEY_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/etcd1-key.pem"
          Environment="ETCD_PEER_TRUSTED_CA_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/ca.pem"
          Environment="ETCD_PEER_CLIENT_CERT_AUTH=true"
```

welp.. I'm pretty lost. it's the first time this kind of problem happens to me. any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

just in case.. these are the manifests in `/etc/kubernetes/manifests` that aren't being executed. `rkt list --full` doesn't show that any type of pod is starting besides the regular hyperkube.

kube-apiserver.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kube-apiserver
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  hostNetwork: true
  containers:
  - name: kube-apiserver
    image: quay.io/coreos/hyperkube:v1.6.0-beta.0_coreos.0
    command:
    - /hyperkube
    - apiserver
    - --bind-address=0.0.0.0
    - --etcd-servers=http://127.0.0.1:4001
    - --allow-privileged=true
    - --service-cluster-ip-range=10.3.0.0/24
    - --secure-port=443
    - --advertise-address=192.168.1.2
    - --admission-control=NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,DefaultStorageClass,ResourceQuota
    - --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver.pem
    - --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver-key.pem
    - --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.pem
    - --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver-key.pem
    - --runtime-config=extensions/v1beta1/networkpolicies=true,batch/v2alpha1=true
    - --anonymous-auth=false
    livenessProbe:
      httpGet:
        host: 127.0.0.1
        port: 8080
        path: /healthz
      initialDelaySeconds: 15
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    ports:
    - containerPort: 443
      hostPort: 443
      name: https
    - containerPort: 8080
      hostPort: 8080
      name: local
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/ssl
      name: ssl-certs-kubernetes
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
      name: ssl-certs-host
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/ssl
    name: ssl-certs-kubernetes
  - hostPath:
      path: /usr/share/ca-certificates
    name: ssl-certs-host
```

kube-controller-manager.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kube-controller-manager
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - name: kube-controller-manager
    image: quay.io/coreos/hyperkube:v1.6.0-beta.0_coreos.0
    command:
    - /hyperkube
    - controller-manager
    - --master=http://127.0.0.1:8080
    - --leader-elect=true
    - --service-account-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver-key.pem
    - --root-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.pem
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 200m
    livenessProbe:
      httpGet:
        host: 127.0.0.1
        path: /healthz
        port: 10252
      initialDelaySeconds: 15
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/ssl
      name: ssl-certs-kubernetes
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
      name: ssl-certs-host
      readOnly: true
  hostNetwork: true
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/ssl
    name: ssl-certs-kubernetes
  - hostPath:
      path: /usr/share/ca-certificates
    name: ssl-certs-host
```

kube-proxy.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kube-proxy
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    rkt.alpha.kubernetes.io/stage1-name-override: coreos.com/rkt/stage1-fly
spec:
  hostNetwork: true
  containers:
  - name: kube-proxy
    image: quay.io/coreos/hyperkube:v1.6.0-beta.0_coreos.0
    command:
    - /hyperkube
    - proxy
    - --master=http://127.0.0.1:8080
    - --cluster-cidr=10.2.0.0/16
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
      name: ssl-certs-host
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /var/run/dbus
      name: dbus
      readOnly: false
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /usr/share/ca-certificates
    name: ssl-certs-host
  - hostPath:
      path: /var/run/dbus
    name: dbus
```

kube-scheduler.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kube-scheduler
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  hostNetwork: true
  containers:
  - name: kube-scheduler
    image: quay.io/coreos/hyperkube:v1.6.0-beta.0_coreos.0
    command:
    - /hyperkube
    - scheduler
    - --master=http://127.0.0.1:8080
    - --leader-elect=true
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 100m
    livenessProbe:
      httpGet:
        host: 127.0.0.1
        path: /healthz
        port: 10251
      initialDelaySeconds: 15
      timeoutSeconds: 15
```

Comment: I would investigate `container runtime is down PLEG is not healthy` if I were you.

Comment: @AntoineCotten - doesn't it mean that the rkt api-service is not working properly ? how can I sanity test the rkt api-service to make sure it works? I only found a go program on google that I was unable to properly compile in the coreos toolbox

Comment: Hard for me to tell, my experience with rkt is really basic. Your kubelet starts, and as far as I understand it's running inside a rkt container itself, so maybe this container is missing permissions to interact with rkt. I suggest: 1) trying with k8s v1.5 - 2) trying to run kubelet outside of the wrapper

Comment: @AntoineCotten - you helped me resolve the issue. thank you very much

Comment: sweet! Would you mind sharing the solution in your own answer?

Comment: @AntoineCotten - just did. thanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thanks to @AntoineCotten the problem was easily resolved.

first, I downgraded hyperkube from `v1.6.0-beta.0_coreos.0` to `v1.5.3_coreos.0`. then I noticed an error in the kubelet log that made me understand that I had a major typo in `/opt/bin/host-rkt`.

I had `exec nsenter -m -u -i -n -p -t 1 -- /usr/bin/rkt "\$@"` instead of `exec nsenter -m -u -i -n -p -t 1 -- /usr/bin/rkt "$@"`.

I escaped the `$` when trying to paste the command line arguments, which then.. didn't. so.. not using 1.6.0-beta0 for now, that's ok! and fixed the script. now everything works again. thanks